# How to compute user defined variables with a mysql database table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a website that will need to process some data that is in a database table with a form that the user fills out. There is kind of a lot of data but a simple example would be something like this:

[image: example]

In this I am multiplying the answer to each form question with its corresponding column.

Is this something that can be done or do I need to set it up in a different way?

Comment: Without any code for the form, or schemas for the tables, and a better description of your process, there is no way to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too broad to answer, however, focusing on only your first table, a normalised version of same might look like this:

```
 hour fruit  quantity
    1 apple     3 
    1 orange    2
    1 melon     3
    2 apple     2
    2 orange    2
    2 melon     2
    3 apple     1
    3 orange    3
    3 melon     2
```